# Changing output filename during org-publish

Tags: org-mode, org-publish

I would like to change the name of the generated html file of all files during an org-publish.

As per [the docs](https://orgmode.org/manual/Export-Settings.html): unless EXPORT_FILE_NAME is set, "Org generates the file name based on the buffer name and the extension based on the back-end format".  I don't want to set EXPORT_FILE_NAME per file however - I'd like to define a function that determines the filename for all files during publish.  (In my case, based on the org file's TITLE property).

For example:

- my filename might be `20201003123706-commonspub.org`
- the file has the #+TITLE property of **CommonsPub**.
- At present my output html file will be called `20201003123706-commonspub.html`
- But I would like to be `CommonsPub.html`.

I am publishing via `org-publish-project-alist` with `:publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html`.